# Calling a function when the background image finishes loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am loading a remote file as a background image, and it could take up to 2 seconds, depending on the internet connection.

I would like to trigger a function when the background image completes loading.

It would work something like this (although this obviously does not)

> ```
> $("body").css("background image","url('very_big_remote_image')",
>          function(data){alert("done")}
>          );
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, basically I load an image object and set its source to the background. Once it has loaded I change the background and fire the callback:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    $("body").addClass("bg");
    //the callback function call here
};
img.src = 'very_big_remote_image';
```

This image is never shown, just forces browser to load it then it is cached.

Then have this in your css:

```
body.bg {
    /* change the position or repeat or whatever else you need in this line */
    background: url('/path/to/the/image/above.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: its weird  - the image takes a while to load, then the background image does not change, tho the callback is triggered

Comment: Do this instead of that .css line: $("body").addClass("bg");  then have a css body.bg {background : url("path to that image")}

Comment: it works great, thanks! i hate the syntax for background, trips me up everytime ;)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a load event function with a callback mechanism:

```
$("<img />").attr('src', 'img/pic.png').load(function() { /* Do stuff */ });
```

There are a number of variations.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I don't believe that will tach background images.

Comment: It will work - I intended the /* Do stuff */ comment to be where you actually set the background image.  moe's solution fleshes it out fully.

Comment: thanks a lot j, u are right that this works, when you combine it with the background image change =)