# jquery link click switching image before next page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a clickable div like

```
<a href="/go/to/link">
<div class="background-image"></div>
</a>
```

I want to switch the background image of that div onclick before redirecting the suer.

I am doing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".background-image").click(function() {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/newimage)');
        });
    });
```

This doesnt work and onclick the image never laods. However if I add a return false to it  like this

```
$(".background-image").click(function() {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/newimage)');
                    return false;
        });
```

then image shows up but now page doesnt redirect to the link. What can I do here.
thanks

Comment: in your example without the return false, does it redirect?

Comment: Yes it does redirect if I dont use return false

Comment: @Autolycus -- Here's what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365509/calling-a-function-when-the-background-image-finishes-loading :: You'll need to essentially load the image up in memory, and in the callback of the `load` function, change the css.

Comment: are you using jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I actually tried my original solution without the images being cached and it wasn't working for me, I think the following should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/ma2zY/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".background-image").click(function (e) {
        var that = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://www.gq.com/images/style/2012/04/simpsons-style/simpsons-96.jpg').load(function () {
            $(that).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.gq.com/images/style/2012/04/simpsons-style/simpsons-96.jpg)').delay(1).queue(function () {
                window.location = $(that).closest('a').prop('href');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This loads the image and waits for the image to be loaded before swapping it out and continuing. I also added a `delay()` that you can use to make it wait longer if you wish, it's currently set at 1 which is nothing really.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the loading of image 
when I do this

```
<a href="/go/to/link">
<img src="/somenewimage" style="display:none">
<div class="background-image"></div>
</a>
```

it works as it loads the image in the memory before the click is activated. Not sure if thats the best way to do it but this is the only way I could get it to work

Comment: There's nothing wrong with preloading images. Did my original solution actually work for you? I noticed that you accepted it... but I updated it because I was finding it didn't work for me if I didn't have the images cached.